# Google Cloud SQL showing "Instance is being updated" more than 10h and DONT STARTS

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Google Cloud SQL showing "Instance is being updated" more than 10h and DONT STARTS!

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Cloud SQL. Monitoring noticed your down instance and there's a ticket pending investigation by an engineer right now. 
[I'm the Cloud SQL tech lead]